# getting pascals to print in multiple rows

Tags: python, list

I have Pascal's Triangle created however it all prints on one line.  Any advice how to get it to print in rows (not in triangle shape)?

```
row=input("Please enter height: ")
triangle=[]
for rownum in range (0,row+1):
   newvalue=1
   newrow=[]
   if row==0:
       newrow.append(int(newvalue))

   elif row==1:
       newrow.append(int(newvalue,newvalue))

   else:

       for column in range(rownum):
         if column==0:
             newrow.append(1)
         elif column==(rownum-1):
             newrow.append(int(newvalue))
         else:
             new_value=triangle[rownum-1][column]+triangle[rownum-1][column-1]
             newrow.append(int(new_value))
   triangle.append(newrow)
print triangle
```

Comment: Don't just `print` a list. Iterate through it and print each line.

Comment: @Wooble: Answers should be put in answers, not in comments.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I saw it as more of a hint than a full answer, but I suppose answering first with a hint may have dissuaded 2 other people from doing his homework for him completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(str(n) for n in row) for row in triangle)

1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Alternatively, use `str.center` to align things nicer:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(str(n) for n in row).center(80) for row in triangle)

                                       1                                        
                                      1 1                                       
                                     1 2 1                                      
                                    1 3 3 1                                     
                                   1 4 6 4 1                                    
                                 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

To preserve the geometry correctly for larger scales, you could use `str.format` tricks like this:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join('{:3d}'.format(n) for n in row).center(80) for row in triangle)

                                        1                                       
                                      1   1                                     
                                    1   2   1                                   
                                  1   3   3   1                                 
                                1   4   6   4   1                               
                              1   5  10  10   5   1                             
                            1   6  15  20  15   6   1                           
                          1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1                         
                        1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1                       
                      1   9  36  84 126 126  84  36   9   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the last line to:

```
for line in triangle:
  print str(line)
```

gives this:

```
[]
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Changing the last line to:

```
i = row
for line in triangle:
  print ' ' * i + str(line)
  i -= 1
```

gives this:

```
      []
     [1]
    [1, 1]
   [1, 2, 1]
  [1, 3, 3, 1]
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

Finally, changing it to this:

```
i = row
for line in triangle:
  str_line = [str(e) for e in line]
  print (' ' * i) + ' '.join(str_line)
  i -= 1
```

gives this:

```
     1
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I felt sorry for you . This is the answer to your deleted question.....

For example, any string value has a method called center that produces a new string with the old
value centered, using extra spaces to pad the value out to a given length. The general form is:

```
s.center(n)
```

This method takes one argument n, the size of the result. Examples:

```
>>> k = "Ni"
>>> k.center(5)
' Ni '
>>> "<*>".center(12)
' <*> '
```

Note that in the first example we are asking Python to center the string "Ni" in a field of length 5.
Clearly we can't center a 2-character string in 5 characters, so Python arbitrarily adds the extra space
character before the old value.

Another useful string method left-justifies a value in a field of a given length. The general form:

```
s.ljust(n)
```

For any string expression s, this method returns a new string containing the characters from s with
enough spaces added after it to make a new string of length n.

```
>>> "Ni".ljust(4)
'Ni '
>>> "Too long to fit".ljust(4)
'Too long to fit'
```

Note that the .ljust() method will never return a shorter string. If the length isn't enough, it just returns
the original value.

There is a similar method that right-justifies a string value:

```
s.rjust(n)
```

This method returns a string with enough spaces added before the value to make a string of length n.
As with the .ljust() method, it will never return a string shorter than the original.

```
>>> "Ni".rjust(4)
' Ni'

>>> m = "floccinaucinihilipilification"
>>> m.rjust(4)
'floccinaucinihilipilification'
```

Sometimes you want to remove whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines) from a string. For a string s,
use these methods to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

• s.strip() returns s with any leading or trailing whitespace characters removed.
• s.lstrip() removes only leading whitespace.
• s.rstrip() removes only trailing whitespace.

```
>>> spaceCase = ' \n \t Moon \t\t '
>>> spaceCase
' \n \t Moon \t\t '

>>> spaceCase.strip()
'Moon'

>>> spaceCase.lstrip()
'Moon \t\t '

>>> spaceCase.rstrip()
' \n \t Moon'
```